# Limit public access to AWS ECS Fargate Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-ip, amazon-ecs, security-groups

- I have a service on AWS ECS deployed using Fargate.
- This service uses a Network Load Balancer (NLB) to allow an Elastic IP to be associated with the service.
- This is not an http service and is using port 5060
  (SIP), hence the choice of an NLB.

I am not quite understanding something in regards to the health checks. If I limit access in the Security Group associated with the service to just a few /32 (single IPs) for the traffic port, the service is marked unhealthy. If I allow access to the world to the traffic port the service is marked healthy. If I allow access to just the internal CIDR block including the NLB, the service is marked healthy -- BUT that also allows world access to the port.

I tried making the health check use another port on the container, but this is less than ideal and I didn't get that working successfully. While I'd welcome an answer that detailed how to set that up properly given my Fargate/NLB/Elastic IP requirement, I'd rather have the traffic port just be the health check port, but I need to understand a way to deny world access to the port.

Comment: My approach here would be to work out what is doing the health check (NLB I assume), the port(s) it uses, and the source IP range of the health check, permit those IPs in. I have seen this information online, but I can't locate it right now.

Comment: Thanks Tim. It's a reasonable approach but the service is running a container with little ability to do debug like that. I may try adding in a service with a container more suited to debugging if I can't find the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to figure out where do the health checks come from and whitelist those IPs. Since it's a Fargate container and you presumably don't have SSH access to it you can try one of these avenues:

1. Does the SIP service **log incoming connections**? If it does and if the logs are forwarded to e.g. *[CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html)* (and they should be!) you can have a look there.
2. Use **[VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html)** to figure out what IPs are connecting to your service. It's best to know the *ENI ID* (elastic network interface ID) of your container - it is displayed in the Fargate Task details.

You also mention that when you whitelist the internal VPC IP range the service gets open to the world. That doesn't sound right - can you post a screenshot of your Security Group settings in that case?

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I used the VPC Flow Logs to figure it out. Thanks, wasn't aware of that service.